# Navigate programatically through nested object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, recursion, path, nested

I have a **nested object** and a **path**, which describes a position in the object. I would like to access the object at the end of the tree with the given path. For example I would like to get the id of the object, where the path is *"contracts/access/roles/MinterRole.sol"*. How could I do it? Is it possible without recursively iterating over the whole tree? Thank you!

My object looks like the following:

```
{  
   "name":"contracts",
   "toggled":true,
   "id":0,
   "children":[  
      {  
         "name":"access",
         "toggled":false,
         "id":1,
         "children":[  
            {  
               "name":"Roles.sol",
               "id":2,
               "path":"contracts/access/Roles.sol",
               "dependencies":[  

               ]
            },
            {  
               "name":"roles",
               "toggled":false,
               "id":3,
               "children":[  
                  {  
                     "name":"CapperRole.sol",
                     "id":4,
                     "path":"contracts/access/roles/CapperRole.sol",
                     "dependencies":[  
                        {  
                           "fileName":"Roles.sol",
                           "absolutePath":"contracts/access/Roles.sol"
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {  
                     "name":"MinterRole.sol",
                     "id":5,
                     "path":"contracts/access/roles/MinterRole.sol",
                     "dependencies":[  
                        {  
                           "fileName":"Roles.sol",
                           "absolutePath":"contracts/access/Roles.sol"
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {  
                     "name":"PauserRole.sol",
                     "id":6,
                     "path":"contracts/access/roles/PauserRole.sol",
                     "dependencies":[  
                        {  
                           "fileName":"Roles.sol",
                           "absolutePath":"contracts/access/Roles.sol"
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {  
                     "name":"SignerRole.sol",
                     "id":7,
                     "path":"contracts/access/roles/SignerRole.sol",
                     "dependencies":[  
                        {  
                           "fileName":"Roles.sol",
                           "absolutePath":"contracts/access/Roles.sol"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd split the path at the slash, then just iterate through it. It makes it easier if you wrap the entire object in an array as well.

```
const pathParts = path.split("/");
let currentNode = mainTree;
pathParts.forEach(part => {
    if (currentNode && currentNode.children) {
        currentNode = currentNode.children.find(child => child.name === part);
    }
});
```

Note that while this is iterative, it will still stop at the node on a given level that matches the path name, skipping anything after. As long as the tree isn't ordered (i.e. a binary tree or something), that's the best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is the way to go.

You may want to take a look at the semi-famous [walk the DOM snippet](https://gist.github.com/johntran/9ffd7afd988003b3844e) by D. Crockford himself.

What you want to do is to adapt that snippet to your data and augment the code with extra logic to stop the recursion if a result has been found.